# How to create calculated column off variable result of same row? Pandas & Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Fairly new to python, I have been struggling with creating a calculated column based off of the variable values of each item.

I Have this table below with DF being the dataframe name

[image]

I am trying to create a 'PE Comp' Column that gets the PE value for each ticker, and divides it by the **Industry ** average PE Ratio.

My most successful attempt required me creating a .groupby industry dataframe (**y**) which has calculated the mean per industry. These numbers are correct. Once I did that I created this code block:

```
for i in DF['Industry']:

DF['PE Comp'] = DF['PE Ratio'] / y.loc[i,'PE Ratio']
```

However the numbers are coming out incorrect. I've tested this and the y.loc divisor is working fine with the right numbers, meaning that the issue is coming from the dividend.

Any suggestions on how I can overcome this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Pandas [Groupby transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

The following takes the `PE Ratio` column and divides it by the mean of the grouped industries (expressed three different ways in order of speed of calculation):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"PE Ratio": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                   "Industry": list("AABCBBC")})

# option 1
df["PE Comp"] = df["PE Ratio"] / df.groupby("Industry")["PE Ratio"].transform("mean")

# option 2
df["PE Comp"] = df.groupby("Industry")["PE Ratio"].transform(lambda x: x/x.mean())

# option 3
import numpy as np
df["PE Comp"] = df.groupby("Industry")["PE Ratio"].transform(lambda x: x/np.mean(x))

df
#Out[]: 
#   PE Ratio Industry   PE Comp
#0         1        A  0.666667
#1         2        A  1.333333
#2         3        B  0.642857
#3         4        C  0.727273
#4         5        B  1.071429
#5         6        B  1.285714
#6         7        C  1.272727
```

Comment: Groupby objects have a `mean` method.

Comment: Is that not option 1?  Otherwise, using `groupby()["col"].mean()` would return a pd.Series with row length equal to unique industries (and so would need to be mapped).

Comment: The PE Comp results in your table shows the percentage of  the total sum of PE Ratio per industry (i.e: 33% for the total sum of PE Ratio 3) whereas I am trying to find the PE Ratio compared to industry average (i.e. 0.666 against the Industry (A) average of 1.5)

Comment: You might have seen the very first table, I updated it a minute after posting with the corrected output.  So 1/1.5 for the first row is 0.667, with 1 being PE Ratio, and 1.5 being the average for all industry A ratios.

Answer (score 0):

First, you MUST NOT ITERATE through a dataframe. It is not optimized at all and it is a misused of Pandas' DataFrame.
Creating a new dataframe containing the averages is a good approach in my opinion. I think the line you want to write after is :

```
df['PE comp'] = df['PE ratio'] / y.loc[df['Industry']].value
```

I just have a doubt about `y.loc[df['Industry']].value` maybe you don't need `.value` or maybe you need to cast the value, I didn't test. But the spirit is that you new `y` DataFrame is like a `dict` containing the average of each Industry.

Comment: The 'y' dataframe gathers the average per industry for each metric, spanning beyond just PE Ratio. Would a specifier such as:    y.loc[ df['Industry], df['PE Ratio']].value   work? I'll be testing it soon